# Has SourceTree 1.9.5.0. fixed the alert window bug?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I have been using a pretty new SourceTree version (1.9.4.x) and had observed a reoccurring bug stating that a log file no longer cannot be reached. Whenever I selected a change set, if the bug occurred for some reason, then the program did not show any changes, just in the case of closing and reopening it. This flaw was so annoying that I had to close the program 10 days a day sometimes just to reopen it. A friend installed an older, stable version. My question is: can someone confirm that the bug has been fixed? I have installed version 1.9.5.0 a few hours ago and did not encounter the problem with it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the bug was fixed by version 1.9.5.0.